# Solve $e^{4z} +e^{3z} + e^{2z} + e^z + 1 = 0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Solve $$e^{4z} +e^{3z} + e^{2z} + e^z  + 1 = 0.$$

I have attempted this problem with the usual definition by writing $z=x+iy$ and using $e^z = e^x(\cos y + i \sin y)$ but got a large unsolvable mess. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You have an $x$ in the exponent of the first term while $z$'s in the exponent of the remaining terms.  Is this intentional?  What do you know about roots of unity and their sums?

Comment: @JMoravitz Sorry, fixed. And I know nothing of them.

Comment: To elaborate on my hint, the $n^{th}$ roots of unity are the $n$ solutions to the equation $z^n=1$, or written another way, $z^n-1=0$.  One learns, from [efforts like these](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38972/intuitive-understanding-of-why-the-sum-of-nth-roots-of-unity-is-0) that the sums of the roots of unity is zero.  If $e^z$ happens to be a primitive fifth root of unity (i.e. not equal to one), then...

Comment: Just substitute $e^z=u$, find that $u$ is a primitive $5$-th root of unity, and take it from there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$e^{4z}+e^{3z}+e^{2z}+e^z+1=0$ is too hard to solve directly. Instead, solve
\begin{equation}
e^{5z}-1=(e^z-1)(e^{4z}+e^{3z}+e^{2z}+e^z+1)=0
\end{equation}
and remove roots that are not roots of original equation.

Comment: Wow. Can I ask how you spotted that? For future use?

Comment: It is a geometric series that he summed.  The ratio is $e^z$

Comment: Also can use a substitution $u = e^z$.

Comment: @MathMajor All polynomials of the form $\sum\limits_{n\ge i\ge 0}x^i$ have that nice property.